# How to return the count of input that start with a string in XSL?

Tags: string, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to return the count of names which start with NB but im having trouble as it returns 0. I believe i got the syntax right so it's kind of frustrating to see it return 0. Any help would be appreciated!

XML Input:

```
    <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <breaches>
        <breach>
            <name>NB111</name>
            <severity>MAJOR</severity>
        </breach>
        <breach>
            <name>NB222</name>
            <severity>MAJOR</severity>
        </breach>
        <breach>
            <name>NB333</name>
            <severity>MAJOR</severity>
        </breach>
        <breach>
            <name>PO999</name>
            <severity>MAJOR</severity>
        </breach>
    </breaches>
```

XSL

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/breaches/breach/name/*[contains(text(), 'NB')])" />
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(breaches/breach/name[contains(., 'NB')])" />
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS86

Comment: Thank you! I wish i had reputation to give you an upvote. May I just ask how you spotted the issue and what the . dot means syntax wise?

Comment: You can accept the answer if it answers your question (regardless of your reputation). The . (dot) means current item. So in this case we are checking if the current text contains 'NB'.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to return the count of names which start with NB

If you want to count names that start with "NB" then use the `starts-with()` function, not the `contains()` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(breaches/breach[starts-with(name, 'NB')])"/>
```

This actually counts `breach` elements that have a child `name` element that starts with "NB". IOW, it assumes each `breach` has only one `name`. If such assumption is incorrect, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(breaches/breach/name[starts-with(., 'NB')])"/>
```

to count the actual `name` elements.